# Centering text wile using float already?

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem... I'm building a site for someone, and I'm stuck with the menu. I want them in a horizontal row, so in my CSS I'm doing this:

```
.kop {
    font-family: 'Ballpark';
    font-size:45px;
    color:#222;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 10px;

}

.menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <p class="kop">About Us</p>
    <p class="kop">Services</p>
    <p class="kop">Projects</p>
    <p class="kop">Partners</p>
    <p class="kop">Contact Us</p>
</div>
```

It still aligns everything to the left...

Does anyone have an answer?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJR84/)

Lisa.

Comment: have any of these helped you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should correct the CSS, you are setting styles on a class caled "menu" but it is set as an id in your html so it should be `#menu` and not `.menu`.

Second, you should use `display:inline-block` on your menu items instead of floating them left so you can center them in `#menu` with `text-align:center;`. See the following demo :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/9RjWL/)**

CSS :

```
.kop {
    font-family: 'Ballpark';
    font-size:45px;
    color:#222;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 10px;

}
#menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @user3566010 sorry, I had forgotten to update the fiddle. It is now fixed and you can see th working demo in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Menu-bars IMHO people should use an un-ordered list with the CSS style of `display: inline-block;` as it achieves what you want with relative ease.

`display: inline-block;` Does however work with any group of elements, so if you add it to your current CSS it will still display the way you want it to so long as you get rid of your float.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gJR84/3/

### HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="kop"> About Us </li>
    <li class="kop"> Services </li>
    <li class="kop"> Projects </li>
    <li class="kop"> Partners </li>
    <li class="kop"> Contact Us </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.kop {
    font-family: 'Ballpark';
    font-size:45px;
    color:#222;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a menu id instead of a class. To add css to an id do something like this:

```
#menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

A hashtag represents an id while a period is for a class

Answer (score 0):

Your `.kop` elements are floated left, so they'll never be in the middle. Try:

```
.kop {
  font-family: 'Ballpark';
  font-size:45px;
  color:#222;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```